# How to know if speech on WebSpeech-API was interrupted?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webspeech-api

I'd like to know if there is some way to listen to when the speech was interrupted. I create a window.speechSynthesis object and then call the 'speak' method. I am using chrome on the android.
It starts successfully, But Talkback screen reader is activated. So, when Talkback speaks some notification, the speech on the synthesis is interrupted, but,  the window.speechSynthesis.speaking propriety keeps true. 
I've tried to get it with SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onerror event but it's not called...
do you know why is it hapenning?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onend` event?

```
speechSynthesisUtteranceInstance.onend = function() { ... };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/onend